# Text Categorization In R for single paragraph

Tags: r, nlp, text-analysis

I have been searching for a solution/library or any function that performs text categorization of a single paragraph without any training involved in R. I need to categorize/classify contact center call data individually. The calls need to be categorized according to the terms used by the agent or caller. The terms may not be consecutive, and so it doesn't follow bigram.

For example, the following sample text should be categorized something like "Router Internet issues"

"Hello thank you for calling XYZ solutions. This is Mark. How can I help you?
Hi, I have been facing issues in connecting to internet. There seems to be some issue with my router. "

I have tried OpenNLP, RTextTools libraries in R, but could not figure out how to process a single paragraph. Does anyone have any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

**Edited**
*As I am a beginner in R so would much appreciate a thorough solution if possible*

Comment: This looks like a very broad question. What did you try? Please add the lines of code including example data - ready to copy-paste-run in R for reproducation.

Comment: Can you create a vector with all unique categories ?

Comment: On the other hand, you can create a vector with key words and use that vector to extract those key words (if any) from each paragraph

Comment: Indeed @lukeA, very broad!

Comment: Thanks for your replies, 

LukeA I tried the solution provided by the RTextTools from here:
https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf

Sotos as I have mentioned that I am a naive in R so would not be able to do so. Can you suggest any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to extract [keywords](http://www.lexically.net/downloads/corpus_linguistics/PC%20Analysis%20of%20Key%20Words%20-%20and%20Key%20Key%20Words.pdf) from a document and using those as tags/labels. You may want to look at this R package {RKEA} - http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/Download/Kea-5.0-Readme.txt